# Why are figure numbers not showing in captions on minipage?

Tags: captions, minipage

I am including a series of figures in minipages (using \captionof for captions) but unfortunately the captions are not showing the figure numbers at all. Can someone help me here please? Code and image below. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}


\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\section{Disability}\label{sect:Disability}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../figures/DisED.pdf}
  \captionof{}{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Both Sexes)}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../figures/DisEDFemale.pdf}
  \captionof{}{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Female)}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../figures/DisEDMale.pdf}
  \captionof{}{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Male)}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to give the counter-type in the first argument of `\captionof`. Instead of `\captionof{}{<stuff>}` use `\captionof{figure}{<stuff>}`.

Comment: your example gives `! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \SweaveOpts`  and  `! Undefined control sequence.
l.21   \captionof`   Please make sure any example you post is an example of the problem you are asking about

Comment: Thanks Skillmon. Your solution just put "figure" in the caption but no number. I then put \use-package{capt-of} and it fixed the numbering. Apols David, I was using sweave in R  and forgot to remove some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example does not define `\captionof` at all but if the example is fixed to be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}


\section{Disability}\label{sect:Disability}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
%  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../figures/DisED.pdf}
  \captionof{}{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Both Sexes)}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%


\end{document}
```

Then it generates the error

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter '' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13   \captionof{}
                   {Percentage of Population with a Disability (Both Sexes)}
?
```

After *any* error the pdf is just a debugging aid and not intended to be usable.

The error message highlights the empty argument, which should be `figure`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}


\section{Disability}\label{sect:Disability}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
%  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../figures/DisED.pdf}
  \captionof{figure}{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Both Sexes)}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks David. I'm using sweave within r to create the files so debugging isn't as easy. I didnt get that error at all within R. your answer works perfectly!

Comment: tex would have generated the error: it must be in the generated log file if nowhere else. R may hide the terminal output (which is unfortunate but not uncommon for systems using tex in the background) @osckt

Answer (score 1):

put *all* in a `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}


\begin{document}
    
\section{Disability}\label{sect:Disability}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figures/DisED.pdf}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figures/DisEDFemale.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vspace{-\medskipamount}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\linewidth}
       \caption{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Both Sexes)}\label{fig:test1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\linewidth}
        \caption{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Female)}\label{fig:test2}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figures/DisEDMale.pdf}
    \caption{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Male)}\label{fig:test3}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert your mini pages with figures in the `figure` environment document and use standard `\caption` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Disability}
\label{sect:Disability}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup{skip=1ex, belowskip=2ex}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics{../figures/DisED.pdf}%
\caption{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Both Sexes)}\label{fig:test1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics{../figures/DisEDFemale.pdf}
\caption{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Female)}\label{fig:test2}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics{../figures/DisEDMale.pdf}
\caption{Percentage of Population with a Disability (Male)}\label{fig:test3}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]